# Could someone please help me to sending mail with PHP?

Tags: php, dns

I spent my whole days on how to send mail. Could someone help me to find out how I can send the mail through PHP.

I want that I not want to install anything on server when I deployed my application. I use phpmailer and feel it's should work for me but it's not.

```
<?php
require("./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    global $error;
    $from  = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $from_name = $_REQUEST['from_name'];
    $subject  = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];
    $to  = $_REQUEST['to'];
    $to  = "defaultmail@live.in";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.ks101.cryonhost.eu';
    $mail->Username = 'testing@test.de';  
    $mail->Password = 'testing';
    $mail->Port = 25;  
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        echo(false);
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        echo(true);
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Here is the detail of SMTP sever

http://www.cryoncom.com/DE/aktuell/ankuendigungen/index.html

I am able to login here http://ks101.cryonhost.eu/poplogin/ with username and password I have.

Could someone help me on how I can send mail. I am still puzzling

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

change your echos so that you see where its going wrong.
Instead of 
    `echo(false);` or in fact instead of also `echo(true);`
Use
    `echo($error);`

And then let us know what message you are getting.

Also and does this work ?

```
    mail('defaultmail@live.in', 'Test', 'This is a test message');
```